Missing Page Setup group in Layout when changing page size in ArcGIS Pro
I am using ArcGIS Pro.
According to Esri, I should be able to change a Layout size by activating the map frame, going to the Layout tab, and then selecting Page Setup. However, under the Layout tab, I only see "Navigate" and "Map (close activation)".
Where I can find this Page Setup>Size option?

The instructions for changing the page size of a layout are provided at Change a layout size.
I suspect that you have misinterpreted the first step which says:


Make the layout you want to resize the current active view.


as being about activating a map frame within a layout.  Instead, it simply means that you need to click on the tab of the Layout view (or use another means) to make that view active.
